# Browser Warning After Removing SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, seo

I canceled my SSL certificate subscription but all my pages are indexed with https on search engines.

So I added a redirect to my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but I still can't go through the old https links without getting a warning:

The certificate for this website is invalid. You might be connecting to a website that is pretending to be www.flashmavi.com, which could put your confidential information at risk.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You still have SSL enabled but your certificate for the site is no longer valid. Thus browsers complain about the invalid certificate. The redirect will only be done inside the SSL connection, that is after the browser complained and the user explicitly ignored the warnings.

Your only ways are either to get a new certificate or to disable SSL completely so that browsers don't get a warning but simply fail and the search engine will update the index after a while. Note that you cannot disable SSL completely for a single host if there are other sites on the same IP address using SSL.